# Getting list of countries through a servlet: is it the right way?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I have a problem. In a web page I have a form. In this form there is a select form element  which should get from a table in a mysql database all the countries when the page is loaded . Here is it the servlet:

```
    @WebServlet(name = "SignUpServlet", urlPatterns =
    {
        "/signup"
})
public class SignUpServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @EJB
    private SignUpBean signUpBean;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        request.setAttribute("CountriesList", signUpBean.getListCountries());

        String arg = "/signup.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(arg);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo()
    {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

When the servlet it is called it should put on the select element all the countries list.
My question is when I submit the form, which function should I call? I mean A servlet is made to handle only one request. How can I put different function in the same servlet?

EDIT

```
    @Override
    public void init()
            throws ServletException
    {
        this.getServletContext().setAttribute("CountriesList", signUpBean.getListCountries());

    }
```

Comment: If you are not passing any thing to the Servlet then simply use `GET` method of form that will call `doGet()` method of servlet instead use `POST`. By the way where is the issue?

Comment: The issue is I don't understand how can I pass more requests to the servlet. Suppose I would like to pass two GET different requests to the same servlet. when the page is loaded I get the list of countries in the select form element. When I submit the form I send a request to the servlet. to do that I can't use the same method processRequest

Comment: Pass a token(a string) from the JSP as query string or as post data and check it in the Servlet and based upon the token call proper method.

Comment: I think that the best way to do what I'd like to do is by using the init() method.